# I want my child component should visible only when it gets all data

Tags: angular

here is my code     [Plunker`<a routerLink="/students">Students List</a>`](https://plnkr.co/edit/LuXW6b2nviNiUtN6q30Z)

Ok my concern is, when I clicks on **Students List** Link.

Anything from **StudentComponent** should not visible until **studentlist** get initialized.

NOTE: I am using settimeout function because my service take some time to return data. So i am using it only to show time delay.

Answer (score 2):

This is what guards are for https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard

> ```ts
> import { Injectable }             from '@angular/core';
> import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot,
>          ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
> import { Crisis, CrisisService } from './crisis.service';
> @Injectable()
> export class CrisisDetailResolver implements Resolve<Crisis> {
>   constructor(private cs: CrisisService, private router: Router) {}
>   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Crisis> {
>     let id = route.params['id'];
>     return this.cs.getCrisis(id).then(crisis => {
>       if (crisis) {
>         return crisis;
>       } else { // id not found
>         this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']);
>         return null;
>       }
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the template with an `*ngIf` so if that condition is satisfied your template will be created:

```
<div *ngIf="students">
    <h1>And here is students list</h1>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let student of students">
        <td>{{student.id}}</td>
        <td>{{student.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Edited plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AhWQPBWZVm0vrZqHY6Jr?p=preview

Comment: Thanx. This is easy, simple and effective answer.

Comment: @JamesJaved Glad I could help. I suggest you to check the resolve guard also as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the [**Resolve-Guard**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard). For a full explanation on how to use them, I suggest you take a look there.

You can pre-fetch data before showing the routed component. Remember to add your guard to your providers array. I kinda forgot that once.